# ios8 silent pushes to a non-running app..

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification, uiapplicationdelegate

Do we need a payload attribute like : "PrettyPlease":1?

I have read what seems like a countless number of posts on this subject. After realizing iOS7 won't wake a swipe-killed app, and moving to iOS8 because of the promise of "content-available":1 actually working as advertised, i am sitting here wondering if my reading comprehension is just lacking.

I have implemented every possible nuance i have read, including adding an innocuous "sound":"" to my payload, but about 99% of the time: no app awakening. The 1% of the time my console shows: Silent Push: Deny app not running. The one time i thought i was receiving pushes, i am sure i simply accidentally had left the app running in the background but was so elated to see action that i forgot to check the receiving method.

Pushes work perfectly when the app is running or in the background and are a thing of magic, thus my general setup is correct. But, moving to debug, and watching for Xcode to fire up the up and drop an NSLog into the console for a push that is successfully sent from source, nothing. Nada. I have wiped apps completely, restarted Xcode, restarted my dev box, danced around a fire, pissed into the wind, and even held my breath till blue in the face.

I am at a loss, and about to code a workaround that involved lots of db activity, timed-loops etc, all because a promised feature by Apple seems very Windows-like.

Does anyone have a link to a very clear and concise tutorial/example/demo that actually works, or shows a project that will work provided a push is being received by a non-running app?

Any other thoughts would be appreciated. I know there are many similar threads, but none provide any solid answer (at least for me).

Comment: An app has to be started once after install to be able to receive APNs. It can be killed afterwards and will still be able to receive the calls.

Comment: Sacrifice a goat to the great overlord and pray for apple to be more helpful to the developers...... In my app the production push notification stuff works exactly as advertised on ad-hoc and app-store builds but the moment i try to debug development push notifications all hell breaks loose.

Comment: ***If*** production push notifications work as expected for you as well and ***if*** 'logging' push notification stuff can suffice, try third party logging APIs like [papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com) or [loggly](https://www.loggly.com) in an ad-hoc build

Comment: In my situation, i am pre-submission and cannot risk the process without having it work development side. I feel i must be missing something very very basic, but as yet, every single thing i have read, i have tried, and the closest i get is the "Silent Push: Deny app not running" error, as well as about 50% of the time, the debugger will not attach to the device awaiting the push. The only remedy there seems to be to wipe the app completely, and then restart.  All this feels very un-Apple like, at least in my experiences..

Comment: @dogsgod: i always  run the app once, to establish the proper currentUser within the appspace, thus ensure i avoid an attempt to fire up the app without the proper user.

Comment: I am now wondering if incorrect code practices (while getting up to speed) with respect to calling completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult***); may have somehow flagged APNS to not send pushes through? I hope not, but wonder as there are few other angles left to figure this out with.